# How to change the itemize color in Madrid and beaver theme in beamer?

Tags: beamer, color, enumerate, itemize

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} % dvipsnames gives more built-in colors
%\geometry{hmargin={1.14in,1.14in}, vmargin={1.02in,.99in}}

\usepackage{graphicx}% for "\scalebox" macro

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2016-12-29]
\usepackage{bigints}
%\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{infolines} % Alternatively: miniframes, infolines, split
%\useinnertheme{circles}
\usecolortheme{beaver} %gray and red color theme


\usefonttheme{serif} %times new roman 


%\usecolortheme[named=UBCblue]{structure}
\usecolortheme[named=Mahogany]{structure} % Sample dvipsnames color

\title[Short title]{Big Title }
\date{\today}
\author[Author]{author list}
\institute[]{Department\\University }

\begin{document}


{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{} 
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Objectives} 
    objectives  
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Objective no 1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Obs-2
        \item  Obs-3
    \end{itemize}

    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I change the bullet color? I want only the numbers to enumerate. Why the bullet color in `\item` is so dark. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You could simply add a `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[default]` at the end of your preamble. Regarding the *darkness* of the color, it is the way the theme is defined. If you do not like this theme, why choose it ?

Comment: Any news on this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can control the colour of the itemize/enumerate ball, which is used by your combination of themes, via `\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=yellow,fg=black}`

Other comments:

- no need to hack the frame counter, you can exclude the title frame from being counted with the `noframenumbering` option
- no need to load the `graphicx` package, beamer does this automatically

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} % dvipsnames gives more built-in colors
%\geometry{hmargin={1.14in,1.14in}, vmargin={1.02in,.99in}}

%\usepackage{graphicx}% for "\scalebox" macro

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2016-12-29]
\usepackage{bigints}
%\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{infolines} % Alternatively: miniframes, infolines, split
%\useinnertheme{circles}
\usecolortheme{beaver} %gray and red color theme


\usefonttheme{serif} %times new roman 


%\usecolortheme[named=UBCblue]{structure}
\usecolortheme[named=Mahogany]{structure} % Sample dvipsnames color

\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=yellow,fg=black}

\title[Short title]{Big Title }
\date{\today}
\author[Author]{author list}
\institute[]{Department\\University }

\begin{document}


{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{} 
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
}




\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Objectives} 
    objectives  
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Objective no 1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Obs-2
        \item  Obs-3
    \end{itemize}

    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sory, very late ... +1 for interesting answer. I wonder, isn't is sufficient write title frame as `\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}` ?

Comment: @Zarko For this particular case one could indeed use a plain frame. In general there would be a difference with the headline.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. So far I didn't met a theme where plain didn't work :-), bur recently I rare use `beamer`. In spar time I would do some more research about `beamer` themes!

Comment: How can we also control their shape like squares, triangle, etc?

Comment: @HoseinRahnama If you have a new question, please ask a new question

Comment: Ok, sorry for the annoyance, I will post a new question. :)